# Loader animation on any fetch api request

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api, loader

I want to add loader animation when a fetch API request is loading data. Tried the old jQuery way, but it does nothing for fetch requests.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $(document.body).addClass("loading");    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $(document.body).removeClass("loading"); },
    ajaxError: function() { $(document.body).removeClass("loading"); }   
  });
});
```

I want to add this loader when any fetch API request is made, not only for one particular fetch API request, similarly, like the jQuery code above does. It adds\removes class `loading` when any XMLHtppRequest has started/stopped.

Is there any way of doing this with fetch requests?

Answer (score 1):

set a state for handling the visibility of the animation.

const [animation, setanimation] = useState(false);

const signUp = async () => {

//when the request starts, set the the animation state to true. To make it visible

setanimation(true);

```
await axios
  .post(signup_url, {
    full_name: name,
    date_of_birth: dob,
    phone: phone,
    email: email,
    password: password,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response, "hello response");
```

//and set the animation to false when the request arrives

```
   setanimation(false);

 
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.message, "hello error");
```

//you van also set the animaion to false when the request fails

```
   setanimation(false);
   
  });
```

};